# How to define UserDatabase in Tomcat within a Context xml file?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, tomcat9

I have been experimenting with setting up authentication with Tomcat config by only setting a context file.

Given the following webapp context file `conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
  <Resource
      name="MyUserDatabase"
      auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/myapp-users.xml"
      />
  <Realm
      className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
      resourceName="MyUserDatabase"
      />
</Context>
```

When starting Tomcat, it gives the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [MyUserDatabase] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [MyUserDatabase].
```

However, if I define `<Resource name="MyUserDatabase"...` in `server.xml` under `<GlobalNamingResources>` it works as expected. The [documentation for contexts](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Definitions) clearly shows the `<Resource>` element is valid there.

Is there a special way to reference resources defined in a context file? Or is it just not possible?

In-case it matters, I am dealing with Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the property `localJndiResource="true"` to your realm:

```xml
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
       resourceName="MyUserDatabase"
       localJndiResource="true"/>
```

Without this property Tomcat looks for a resource in `<GlobalNamingResources>` (cf. [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/realm.html#UserDatabase_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm)).

Comment: I confirm it works! - Thanks, I spent ages reading the docs, but alas not the right bit.